# SSIS Flat file import - CSV formatting not good

Tags: ssis

I'm looking to import a CSV, but its formatting isn't great. There is effectively a header section of the CSV which is just two columns, but then this goes onto the bulk of the actual data, which is four columns.

Using the Flat file connection manager, it doesn't see the new lines of the 'header' section, so if I manually stipulate there are four columns, it makes a mess of the upper section. An example of the data would be like so:

```
"Version","1.23""Status","OK""Date","2014.10.04 08:00:00""John","John smith","1234","123456""James","James Pemberton","4567","456789"
```

So, the formatting should be as such:

```
"Version","1.23"
"Status","OK"
"Date","2014.10.04 08:00:00"
"John","John smith","1234","123456"
"James","James Pemberton","4567","456789"
```

So, new lines just don't have a comma after them. Ideally, there would be a couple of extra commas after, say "Version","1.23",, to define the four columns, but this isn't the case, and I can't change the source file.
I'm sure it's easy to solve, but it's getting the better of me this morning!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the data in the first three lines?

Comment: Hi Eric, I could get away with just using the date, but could make a more refined system if I could use that data.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a way of sensibly defining a new row.  The only way you know that its a new row is that there is no comma resulting in a double quotation.

If you create a connection with the row delimiter of double quotation e.g. "" then you will at least get the rows coming into ssis correctly.  You will then have to deal with the varied single/double quotation issues that will occur against each input later within the package.  This would be quite simple to do, however be warned that it may be inefficient on very large data sets

[image: bad formatting result]

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. From what I've read, it could be that SSIS looks for column deliminators before it looks for end of line deliminators. I was hoping a bit of fiddling in the Flat File connection manager, but it seems it's a script job: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/07/14/4226.aspx

Comment: You will need to remove the text qualifier first, which will cause you another issue (handling the speech mark), but will get your data into ssis.